# How to convert Date and Time to timeStamp

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

How can I convert date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format and time in `hh:mm:ss` to Timestamp so that I can save it in hsql database.

Comment: Does `PreparedStatement.setTimestamp` not work in HSql? Avoid string representations as far as you can.

Comment: What is the hosting language? What are the types of time and date (strings? Date? Time?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue converting from java.util.Date to java.sql.Timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864751/issue-converting-from-java-util-date-to-java-sql-timestamp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.sql.Timestamp has a constructor that takes a long, so first we parse your date string using a simple date format then get the time of date (long) and pass it as the argument for the Timestamp contructor.

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(yourDateString)
long time = date.getTime();
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(time);
```

You could also do the following:

```
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("2014-08-18 8:19:15.0");
```

Comment: Thanks Marc for your help let me try that method.